# Search mechanism to search for words both with/without special characters - how to?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

How to make a search mechanism like that:

when user type: `"sól"`
two words are searched: `"sol"` & `"sól"`

and there are search results for both words

Comment: Where does the data come from? Where are you with this? Is this on a mySQL database? If yes, what collation are the tables in that you want to search?

Comment: @Pekka Data comes from mySql datebase. Collation: UTF-8-ci-polish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mySQL collation that is "Umlaut insensitive", for example `utf8_general_ci`.

Either

- Create a specialized search column that is `utf8_general_ci`
- Or define the collation while searching, which is easier but less good for performance. 
  This should work:

  ```
  select * from column where name='sól' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
  ```

  However, doing this may degrade performance in some situations, because I'm quite sure the fulltext index can't be used when specifying the collation like this.